# Laravel eloquent get data from two tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

### **Laravel Eloquent** *Query builder problem*

Hello I have a problem when I am trying to get all the rows where `slug = $slug`.

I will explain in more details:

I have two tables, cards and card_categories.

```
cards has category_id.
card_categories has slug.
```

What I need is a query which returns all the cards which contents the slugs.

For example I made this:

```
$cards = Card::leftJoin('card_categories', 'cards.id', '=', 'card_categories.id')
        ->select('cards.*', 'card_categories.*')
        ->where('card_categories.slug', $slug)
        ->paginate(5);
```

But what happens is that just return 1 row per category.

I don't know what is wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: could you call `->toSql()` on the query to ascertain what the actual sql query looked like? i rarely used query builder directly (mostly uses eloquent models).. i want to help, but i only suspect things going weird on the `leftJoin` or your data simply only have one for each categories..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean, from your explanation I would imagine your card model is as follows.

```
class Card extends Model {
    protected $table = 'cards';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)
    }
}
```

In which case, you should just be able to do this:

```
$cards = Card::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->paginate(5);
```

That will select all of the cards that has the category id of the given slug.

Comment: Many thanks you helped me a lot, it works perfectly, sorry about the explanation.